# Order and degree of DE

Tags: derivatives

I am not understanding how can I find the degree and order of this DE.

$e^{y'''} - xy'' +y = 0$

Should I bring ln here? Please solve for me if you can.

Answer (score 0):

No need to take ln - it won't simplify the equation. We rewrite the question in the form: $f(y^n,y^{n-1},...,y,x)$:

$$f(y''',y'',y,x) = e^{y'''} - xy'' + y = 0$$

The order of a DE is the order of the highest derivative of the dependent variable involved in the function $f$, so this is a 3rd order DE due to the term $e^{y'''}$.

The degree of a DE is the order of the highest derivative of thje dependent variable $f(y^n,y^{n-1},...,y,x)$ but only if $f$ is a *polynomial* with respect to the variables $y^n,y^{n-1},...,y$.

In the case of your equation, $f(y''',y'',y,x) = e^{y'''} - xy'' + y = 0$, we can see that f is NOT a polynomial w/r to the derivatives of y due to the term $e^{y'''}$. Therefore, the degree of your DE is *undefined*.

As an aside, I don't think the degree of a DE is a particularly useful concept mathematically speaking, but the order is important.

Comment: Thank you sir!!

Comment: No problem -  if you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it, thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Accepted sir... Sorry. I am new here.. I don't know all rules

Comment: Sorry.. i made a mistake while typing

Comment: Can u look another time on the question

Comment: It is -xy" ... I mistakenly typed xy"'...sorry for that

Comment: I updated my answer!